# Access VBA can't update table field with string and variable concatenation

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to use a combination of string (text) and a variable input from a form, to update a field in a table.
I can update the field with simple text.
I can output a msg box with the text & variable name.
But when I try to put this into an UPDATE expression the field doesn't update.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
Dim frmYear As Form
Dim ctlYear As Control
           
strSql = "SELECT * FROM IS_Print_Sales"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
Set frmYear = Forms("frmISPrintUpdateYear")
Set ctlYear = frmYear.UpdateYear

db.Execute "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales SET DateCalc = '9/1/2023' WHERE period_name Like '*SEP*'"
db.Execute "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales SET DateCalc = '10/1/'' & ctlYear &' WHERE period_name Like '*OCT*'"
```

In the above two db.Execute statements, the first one (for SEP) works and updates the field, but the second one (for OCT) does nothing.

{If I put this MsgBox code in}
MsgBox "10/1/" & ctlYear

{and then I run the form and input 2023 into the 'UpdateYear' control
The MsgBox pops up with: 10/1/2023 which is what I want to update the table field with}

I've tried various ways with single quotes, double quotes, one &, two & and nothing seems to work.
I've searched online and can't find anything that deals with this issue.

Comment: Pls try `Db.Execute "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales SET DateCalc = '10/1/" & ctlYear & "' WHERE period_name Like '*OCT*'"`. 
A string is always enclosed within double quotation marks.

Comment: Is DateCalc a date/time or text data type field? Since the apostrophes work, my guess is it's a text type. Why not date/time?

Comment: First of all, THANK YOU so much for helping (taller) that worked. I swear I tried every combination of double quotations marks (as you pointed out a string should be enclosed) but I kept getting errors. Clearly I did not actually have this combination. Thank you again, this has been vexing me for a week.

Comment: (June7) it's a bit complicated to explain, because this is part of a much larger issue with multiple spreadsheets (all different) getting imported, but basically it is creating a date/time field I can use later based on a spreadsheet that instead of a date field gives me something that is literally 'JAN23 in the field. It's a complete pain but this now helps solve my problem. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a parameterized query using [DAO.QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) and avoid the challenge of single and double quotes:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, qdef AS DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSql As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM IS_Print_Sales")

' PREPARE STATEMENT (DEFINES PARAMS AND ADDS THEM AS PLACEHOLDERS)
strSql = "PARAMETERS [paramDateString] TEXT(255), [paramPeriodName] TEXT(255); " _
    & "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales " _ 
    & "SET DateCalc = [paramDataString] " _
    & "WHERE period_name LIKE [paramPeriodName];"

' INITIALIZE QUERY OBJECT
Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSql)

' BIND VALUES TO PARAMS AND RUN ACTION
With qdef
   .Parameters("paramDateString") = "9/1/2023"
   .Parameters("paramPeriodName") = "*SEP*"
   .Execute dbfailOnError
End With

With qdef
   .Parameters("paramDateString") = "10/1/'" & Forms!frmISPrintUpdateYear!UpdateYear 
   .Parameters("paramPeriodName") = "*OCT*"
   .Execute dbfailOnError
End With

'...

rs.Close
Set qdef = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: It appears there is an additional single quote in `.Parameters(...) = "10/1/'"` .

Comment: (Parfait) thank you for this. I've done work (years ago) with Access but never did a lot on the VBA side so I'm basically starting over.  I will definitely give DAO.QueryDefs a look. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond with this. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are of data type DateTime, not text, so:

```vb
db.Execute "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales SET DateCalc = DateSerial(2023, 9, 1) WHERE period_name Like '*SEP*'"
db.Execute "UPDATE IS_Print_Sales SET DateCalc = DateSerial(" & ctlYear.Value & ", 10, 1) WHERE period_name Like '*OCT*'"
```

Comment: (Gustav) Thank you for taking the time to respond. This is more complicated than you have time to listen to but basically I have a non-date field that I'm creating the DateCalc field (my name for it because these spreadsheets I'm importing are massive and varied) so it's not actually a date data type it's just something I can use later in the application, but I very much appreciate your response as I will likely run across this later as I'm building out the application.